# Is it haram or halal in Islam to sell a copy of cricket helmet of any brand?

Tags: halal-haram

Assalamu Alaikum!

I sell cricket accessories. I have bought a cricket helmet from the shop to sell. The issue is that the cricket helmet that I bought is a **copy of the original brand**, means that the design of the helmet is **similar to the original brand's helmet** and the original brand's logo is also made on the helmet.

Is it halal or haram to sell a **copy of original brand helmet without original brand logo**?